# Sorting Strings in arbitrary order

Tags: java, sorting

I have a group of Strings which represent product sizes in which most of them are duplicated in meaning but not name. (IE the size Large has at least 14 different spellings possible, each of which needs to be preserved.) I need to sort these based on the size they represent. Any possible Small value should come before any possible Medium value etc.

The only way I see this being possible is to implement a specific Comparator which contains different Sets grouping each size on the base size it represents. Then I can implement the -1,0,1 relationship by determining which Set that particular size falls into.

Is there a more robust way to accomplish this? Specifically I'm worried about 2 weeks from now when someone comes up with yet another way to spell Large.

edit: to be clear its not the actual comparator I have a question with, its the setup with the sets containing each group. Is this a normal way to handle this situation? How do I future proof it so each new size addition doesn't require a full recompile / deploy?

Comment: @downvote: please let me know what the problem with the question was and i'll reconsider

Comment: I think it might be helpful to give more specific examples of what your data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Custom comparator *is* the solution. I do not understand why do you worry that this is not robust enough.

Comment: its not the use of the comparator i'm worried about, its the handling of each item group in sets. added edit for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to load the size aliases from a resourcebundle. Some example code (put all the files in the same package):

An interface to encapsulate the size property

```
public interface Sized {
    public String getSize();
}
```

A product class

```
public class Product implements Sized {

    private final String size;

    public Product(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

A comparator that does the magic:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class SizedComparator implements Comparator<Sized> {

    // maps size aliases to canonical sizes
    private static final Map<String, String> sizes = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        // create the lookup map from a resourcebundle
        ResourceBundle sizesBundle = ResourceBundle
                .getBundle(SizedComparator.class.getName());
        for (String canonicalSize : sizesBundle.keySet()) {
            String[] aliases = sizesBundle.getString(canonicalSize).split(",");
            for (String alias : aliases) {
                sizes.put(alias, canonicalSize);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Sized s1, Sized s2) {
        int result;
        String c1 = getCanonicalSize(s1);
        String c2 = getCanonicalSize(s2);
        if (c1 == null && c2 == null) {
            result = 0;
        } else if (c1 == null) {
            result = -1;
        } else if (c2 == null) {
            result = 1;
        } else {
            result = c1.compareTo(c2);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String getCanonicalSize(Sized s1) {
        String result = null;
        if (s1 != null && s1.getSize() != null) {
            result = sizes.get(s1.getSize());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

SizedComparator.properties:

```
1 = Small,tiny
2 = medium,Average
3 = Large,big,HUGE
```

A unit test (just for the happy flow):

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FieldSortTest {

    private static final String SMALL = "tiny";
    private static final String LARGE = "Large";
    private static final String MEDIUM = "medium";

    private Comparator<Sized> instance;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        instance = new SizedComparator();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHappy() {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products.add(new Product(MEDIUM));
        products.add(new Product(LARGE));
        products.add(new Product(SMALL));

        Collections.sort(products, instance);

        Assert.assertSame(SMALL, products.get(0).getSize());
        Assert.assertSame(MEDIUM, products.get(1).getSize());
        Assert.assertSame(LARGE, products.get(2).getSize());
    }
}
```

Note that ResourceBundles are cached automatically. You can reload the ResourceBundle programmatically with:

```
ResourceBundle.clearCache();
```

(since Java 1.6). Alternatively you could use some [Spring magic](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) to create an auto-reloading message resource.

If reading from a rickety properties file is not cool enough you could quite easily keep your size aliases in a database too.

Comment: There are a couple of interesting ideas in here. Thanks for taking the time to mock it up.

Answer (score 0):

To impose an arbitrary ordering on a collection of strings (or objects in general), the standard means to do this is to implement a Comparator as you suggest.

Apart from the 'manual' solution you suggest, you could consider comparing the relative [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) of strings to canonical examples. This will be more *flexible* in the sense that it will work on alternatives you haven't thought of. But in terms of the work involved, it might be overkill for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll be sure to check it out. It does look like overkill for this though.